# Access another action instance variable from view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, instance-variables

Let's say I have a View `home.html.erb` and the following controller:

```
class StaticController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @people = Person.all
  end

  def filter
    @people = ....
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

Now when the page loads I can easily access those people with `@people`. The problem is when I want to filter those people I call an ajax action from my `home view` and trigger `filter` action and set new `@people` variable.

Inside my View there are still old values of people and not the new ones. When I change the variable name and set it like this:

```
  def filter
    @people2 = ....
  end
```

I receive an error message when I try to iterate through `@people2` inside my View. It says that `@people2` is null. So, my question is how to access that variable from my View?

Thank you.

Comment: Do I understand You correctly - You are looking for away to reload list of people via AJAX ?

Comment: Yes, I don't know any other way.

Answer (score 0):

Why use parameters in a query string to filter?

```
def home
  if params[:gender]
    @people = Person.where(gender: params[:gender])
  else
    @people = People.all
  end
end
```

If you go to `/home.html?gender=male`, `params[:gender]` will return `"male"` and @people will only contain males.

Comment: Instance variable is set the same, all appointments are there. Home is the root view so maybe that could be a problem. Inside my routes I set match '/appointments',  to: 'static#home', via: 'get'. So, my root is set inside 'routes' like this: root  'static#home'